# Can we say somebody is "on a walk" if they went for a walk?

Tags: word-usage, collocations

Let's say somebody is walking for some time, or he/she went for a walk. Can that person say he/she is "on a walk"? Or can we say that about him/her?

**Example sentence:** Let's say I went outside for a walk, and I saw a friend of mine, if he/she asks me what I am doing, can I say, "I am on a walk!"?

Comment: To me, being _on a walk_ implies taking part in a long or organised walk. If I had just stepped out on my own for a stroll round the block or to the local park,  I would say "I'm having a walk" or "I've come out  for a walk".

Comment: See this use NGram, showing that you should probably stick with ***I'm out walking*** rather than ***I'm out on a walk*** (unless, as @Kate says, you're taking part in some relatively "organised" social event).

Comment: Yes.  Your sentence "I am on a walk"  sounds like normal usage to me.  For me, it does not matter if it is a personal walk or an organized walk.  But, for me, "on a walk" does imply that I do not have a specific destination, just out walking.  A very common thing these day with covid.  Lots of people "on a walk" or "out walking" every evening where I live.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- You forgot to include the link to your NGram!

Answer (score 1):

It seems somewhat awkward to me.  The more idiomatic way to say this is "I'm out for a walk" or "I'm taking a walk".  The presumption here is that "a walk" is a definite activity--which it is.

If you instead want to emphasize the action you are taking rather than the slightly-more abstract activity you are doing, you'd say "I'm out walking" or "I'm walking to the park."